# openpyxl start writing from particular column/cell

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I have the following code:

```
ws = wb.worksheets[1]
print(ws)
with open('out.txt', 'r+') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
    print(row)
    ws.append(row)
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

by default it's written to xlsx file starting from A0

Is there a more convinient way to start appending data, let's say from C2?
Or only `xxx.cell(row=xx , column=yy ).value=zz` ?

```
i = 2
j = 3

with open('out.txt', 'r+') as data:
    reader = list(csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t'))
for row in reader:
    for element in row:
        ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value = element
        j += 1
    j = 3
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pad the rows with `None`s

```
ws.append([]) # move to row 2
for row in reader:
   row = (None)*2 + row
   ws.append(row)
```